# How to use spree_bootstrap_theme in Spee

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, spree

I feel a little obscure in understanding the Guide to install spree_bootstrap_theme (https://github.com/Andrewmp1/spree_bootstrap_theme) . Do you have any suggesions for me? Thanks a lot!

Below is what I have done:

1. Create a new sandbox for spree.
2. Add to Gemfile:

   ```
   gem 'spree_bootstrap_theme', :git => 'git://github.com/Andrewmp1/spree_bootstrap_theme.git'
   ```
3. Rename application.css inside stylesheets to application.css.scss
4. Create a new file: bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss inside stylesheets folder.
5. Add to bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss this below line:

   ```
   @import 'store/spree_bootstrap_theme';
   ```
6. Open application.js, add:

   ```
   //= require bootstrap
   ```
7. Run rails server

Result I received: http://imageshack.us/f/405/spreet.png/
As you can see, the layout was broken.
I view source the file and do not see anything about bootstrap. What I got is here:

```
<meta content="Spree demo site" name="description" />
<link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<link href="/assets/normalize.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/skeleton.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/store/screen.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/store/spree_core.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/store/spree_promo.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/store/all.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="BoSR3FtvQBjqF68s7amtXGMVypmaW68e7tHhRzYvqzw=" name="csrf-token" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="/assets/store/checkout.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/store/product.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/store/cart.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/store/spree_core.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/store/spree_promo.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/store/all.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**I TRIED TO ADD gem 'bootstrap-sass' to the Gemfile too but the result in both case is THE SAME as above.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just created a file, inside stylesheets/store, named "spree_bootstrap.scss" with the content:

```
@import 'store/spree_bootstrap_theme'
```

After that, i removed the code below from stylesheets/store/all.css

```
*= require store/spree_core
*= require store/spree_promo
```

And the same for javascripts/store/all.js:

```
//= require store/spree_core
//= require store/spree_promo
```

And i included the following, in javascripts/store/all.js::

```
//= require bootstrap
```

Start your server and you'll see the correct style of spree_bootstrap_theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not rename application.css to application.css.scss . The file application.css is a special purpose file . [Here you can read](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) about its format and syntax .